# Is it possible to develop a React web application and then run it in ElectronJS later?

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-forge

Obviously I wouldn't be able to utilize IPC or persist data but I would like to use Chrome directly to build some UI stuff. If I like the look I thought I could just build up an ElectronJS app around it to handle the actual window stuff. Is that possible or is that asking for problems?

Comment: Yes you could do this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. You can package the react web application as the static resource and then load in electron browse window.